JS : Wait until all files are loaded
context,
i need to upload a lot of files in JS. i have searsh a lot and not find any good answer or the answer not fit my needs.
probleme,
if i wait before clicking (a certain time) all the files have a "content" part, if i clic directly mostly of the files have a "content" part null.
questions,

How can i make my code wait until all the content of all the files to be loaded ?
or
How i can make the button to stay gray until all the files are loaded ?

thx in advance.
the input with the button :
<input id="file" style="width: 600px"></div>
<button id="btn_save_file" class="w2ui-btn" onclick="get_save_file()">Save</button>

the function called :
window.get_save_file = function () { 
    var dataFiles = $('#file').data('selected');
    console.log(dataFiles);
    insertFile(dataFiles);
}

in the console of my browser i see that a lot of files have "content: null" if i click just after selecting files in input. if i wait before clicking the file have a "content" not null.
as requested the insertFile function :
function insertFile(dataFiles) {
   $.ajax({
       url: 'data/UploadFile',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: { request: JSON.stringify(dataFile) }
   )};
}


You should edit your question to include how you are uploading your files. Create a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate your problem.

You added some code, but what does insertFile() do?

it call Ajax query to upload the file

Show your code! You can probably do something when the ajax response is returned.

i add the code of the ajax. so when the code is call some files have no content.

Isn't there a success attribute in the $.ajax() call you can use to call something once it returns? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

i can add a success attribute but what is the point of that  ? if the call is make with file with no content ? i want a way to wait until the file are loaded beafore calling the $.ajax so i have all my file with their content.

I guess I don't understand; You can check the file content on the server-side and return a message if there is no content. That success method is called when the ajax process is complete and returns.

All my file have content, but if i click quickly after selected them (150 files) it appears that a lot of them have no content like they havn't loaded on the page.

How/where are you clicking  quickly after selected them?  Do they appear on your screen after loading them? Are they links? Buttons? You  haven't given any code context for that piece.

I think the best idea (not being given more to work with) would be to look into async/await/Promise functionality in JavaScript. If you create an async function that loads the file, you should be able to track it from the outside using await or a Promise. There are a lot of great options out there!

thanks, can you give me an exemple ? with an input field ?
